# Что лучше передавать значение числа или адрес?

Tags: c++, c, функции, передача-параметров

Что лучше (по скорости) передавать значение числа или адрес 4хбайтного числа?

```
void f1(int i);
void _f1(const int i);
void f2(const int &i);
```

Так же вопросы:

1. Если лучше передавать адрес у 4хбайтного числа, а с булевыми переменными так же?
2. Есть разница между `f1` и `_f1`?
3. Есть ли разница если компилятор для x86/x64?
4. Мысли)

**UDP: после того как заминусовали**

Вопрос возник после того как в Qt Creator воспользовался быстрыми подсказками для установки значения поля. И для `uint32_t` он создавал через константную ссылку. И сейчас выяснил, что такое поведение для всех нестандартных типов. Например для того же `unsigned int` будет создан метод с передачей по значению. Пример:

```
class C {
    uint32_t t;
    unsigned int tt;
public:
    void setT(const uint32_t &value);   // эти методы создал Qt Creator
    void setTt(unsigned int value);     // эти методы создал Qt Creator
};
```

Comment: Лучше для чего? Для оценочных категорий важен контекст.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev скорость выполнения

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev что еще может быть? количество букв?

Comment: Это "экономия на спичках". Такие микрооптимизации лучше оставить компилятору, он их лучше умеет дать.

Comment: Вот вам аналогия: вам нужно передать какой-то предмет кому-то. Если предмет маленький, то проще передать из рук в руки. Если предмет большой - то проще просто сказать где он лежит (может предмет вообще не нужно никуда двигать). Если предметы маленькие, но их много - то тоже проще сказать где они лежат. То же и в программировании - с той разницей что при передаче по значению объект копируется.

Comment: @insolor но на 64-битной машине описание местонахождения предмета будет в два раза больше самого предмета.

Comment: Впрочем, как Microsoft x64 calling convention так и System V AMD64 ABI требует передавать значения через 64-битные регистры, так что на уровне машинного кода разницы между `int` и `int*` не будет.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, поэтому маленький предмет и имеет смысл передавать "из рук в руки".

Comment: И почему вопрос заминусовали?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как минимум между `f1` и `_f1` разница только в том, что в первой функции можно менять значение `i`, во второй - нет, и не более того. Разницы в передаче нет.

При передаче по ссылке скорее всего компилятор соптимизирует все разыменования внутри функции, так что с оптимизацией коды, скорее всего, отличаться сильно не будут. Без оптимизации - основная проблема не в передаче адреса или значения, а в использовании внутри функции значения, переданного по ссылке - что требует разыменования.

*"По-моему, так". (с) Пух*

Вот что делает **без** оптимизации из

```
int f1(int i)
{
    return i*i;
}

int f2(const int& i)
{
    return i*i;
}
```

компилятор VC++ 2017

```
?f2@@YAHAEBH@Z PROC                 ; f2

; 14   : {

    mov QWORD PTR [rsp+8], rcx

; 15   :     return i*i;

    mov rax, QWORD PTR i$[rsp]
    mov rcx, QWORD PTR i$[rsp]
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
    imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rcx]

; 16   : }

    ret 0
?f2@@YAHAEBH@Z ENDP                 ; f2

?f1@@YAHH@Z PROC                    ; f1

; 9    : {

    mov DWORD PTR [rsp+8], ecx

; 10   :     return i*i;

    mov eax, DWORD PTR i$[rsp]
    imul    eax, DWORD PTR i$[rsp]

; 11   : }

    ret 0
?f1@@YAHH@Z ENDP                    ; f1
```

Т.е. основная разница - в косвенном обращении внутри функции, а не в передаче...